# Compare a Python substring to a char value

Tags: python, char, charat

I'm trying to iterate through a loop in Python and compare the current char on a string, with a constant char.

```
for i in s:
        if(s[i]=='I')
            mySum++
```

This code gives me a syntax error on the if statement.

The same code in Java would look something like this

```
for(int i = 0; i<s.length();i++)
{
     if(s.charAt(i)=='I')
         {
          mySum++
         }
}
```

How do I do this in Python?

Comment: `s.count('I')` https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.count

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `+= 1` in python:

```
for i in s:
    if i == 'I':
        mySum += 1
```

Also add a colon after `if`.

Comment: Will this work? If `s` is a string then `i` will be a letter from the string, which cannot be used to index `s`. If `s` is a list, then `i` is an element in the list, which again cannot index the list.

Comment: @ogdenkev Edited my answer

Answer (score 2):

Just like @U12-Forward suggested, there is no `++` operator in python. So you'll have you use the `+=` operator.

However, I prefer @Iain answer rather.

```
my_sum = s.count('I')
```

Answer (score 2):

Problem is not in `if(s[i]=='I')`, the problem is in: `mySum++`.

Python do not support `++` operator.
You can do it by following ways:

```
mySum++ --> mySum +=1

## Or

mySum++ --> mySum = mySum + 1
```